# Matriz N-Esima (Matriz a la N Potencia)

Tags: c++, array-bidimensional, matriz

Segun el enunciado del ejercicio: El usuario debera de ingresar una matriz de nxn, y el valor de N; el programa debera de cumplir con lo siguiente:
 1. Mostrar la Matriz ingresada
 2. Calcular la Matriz N-Esima
 3. Mostrar la Matriz Transpuesta de la Matriz N-Esima

Necesito calcular la Matriz N-esima, y luego hacer la transpuesta de dicha Matriz, pero no logro hacer la Matriz N-Esima.
Si bien, puedo elevarla matriz con un `pow`, pero ello solo me va a regresar el valor de cada elemento elevado a la n potencia.

```
int matn(int x[][MAX], int p, int ord){
for (size_t i=0; i<ord; i++){
    for (size_t j=0; j<ord; j++){
        for (size_t k=0; k<ord; k++){
            B[i][j] = x[i][k]*x[k][j];
        }
    }
}
return pow(B[i][j],p)}
```

Este es mi algoritmo, pero no logro que funcione como deberia, `ord` es el orden la matriz, `int p` es el valor de n que le mando a la funcion, `int x[][MAX]` es la matriz que le envio a la funcion y `B[i][j]` es una matriz global.

Comment: No me queda claro cuál es tu pregunta ¿Tienes problemas con el cálculo de matriz N-Esima, con elevar sus valores o con devolver valores? ¿Qué es la matriz N-Esima?

Comment: La matriz enesima, se puede decir que una Matriz elevada a un exponente, sea, como decir x^2, x^3,...x^n, a lo que voy, es que no tengo un codigo que me multiplique n-veces la matriz dada por el usuario.

Comment: Pero ¿Qué significa elevar la matriz a un exponente? ¿Consiste en elevar cada uno de sus elementos o multiplicar la matriz al completo por si misma varias veces? (lo digo porque la multiplicación de matrices no funciona como multiplicación de números).

Comment: Supongamos que mi exponente n=3, por lo tanto, la matriz A, esta elevada a la 3 (A^3); esto me indica que la matriz A se debe de multiplicar por si misma 3 veces.

Si n=16, la matriz A se debe de multiplicar 16 veces a si misma.
Ejemplo:
n=5, A^5, entonces A se multiplica 5 veces: A * A * A * A * A

Comment: Si gusta, estimado, puede darme su contacto, para enviarle el codigo completo, y asi indicarme en lo que yo este fallando.

Comment: Sólo por aclararlo de una vez por todas. Cuando dices *multiplicar una matriz por si misma* te refieres a [**Multiplicación de matrices**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicación_de_matrices) o a [**Multiplicar los números de las matrices**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicación).

Comment: Me refiero a la multiplicación de matrices, eso es todo.

Comment: Hola, estas realizando más de una vez la misma pregunta, realiza tus preguntas en el sitio en base a [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para elevar matrices primero tienes que implementar la multiplicación. Dado que estamos programando en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) lo apropiado sería hacerlo mediante un objeto:

```
template <unsigned N>
struct Matriz
{
    int datos[N][N]{};
};
```

Al que le implementamos el operador de multiplicación (y escritura en flujo de datos de salida):

```
template <unsigned N>
Matriz<N> operator*(const Matriz<N> &a, const Matriz<N> &b)
{
    Matriz<N> result;

    for (unsigned y = 0; y != N; ++y)
    {
        for (unsigned x = 0; x != N; ++x)
        {
            int value = 0;

            for (unsigned cell = 0; cell != N; ++cell)
            {
                value += (a.datos[cell][y] * b.datos[x][cell]);
            }

            result.datos[x][y] = value;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

template <unsigned N>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Matriz<N> &m)
{
    for (const auto &fila : m.datos)
    {
        for (const auto &valor : fila)
            o << valor << ' ';
        o << '\n';
    }

    return o;
}
```

Con esos operadores y objetos, el siguiente código:

```
Matriz<3> a{1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, -1};
std::cout << a << "*\n" << a << "=\n" << a * a;
```

Generaría la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 1 2 3 
> 1 1 1 
> 0 1 -1 
> *
> 1 2 3 
> 1 1 1 
> 0 1 -1 
> =
> 3 7 2 
> 2 4 3 
> 1 0 2
> ```

Que es lo que cabe esperar:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Sólo falta implementar el operador de potenciar:

```
template <unsigned N>
Matriz<N> operator^(const Matriz<N> &m, int p)
{
    Matriz<N> result = m;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i != p - 1; ++i)
    {
        result = result * m;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVPtboIwFP1Nn@IuSwQVl6n/FHmD8QIOkwrVNAFKoCw4w7Oz3hbwc8mWNFBOz7kfp5coz2fHKGrbV55FSRUz8LgoZcFo6hMiWZonVCqwykp@zFgMgU/UcRVJ@KCy4N/kTCyeSYipFOU2CNU6N2ui1i9qI/MCH0TOCqUqJk4ksrIPiCcj6sIDth9jrgtQsLJKpMpjHUQBzpDjBBt4X6vXywaCNUynpzGxlPKOVhtaPdBqRdM83c8XTSqmKQShW23EksTI9a6PgB8YxESxTIjpBhz6ZuxBQrg9hTCBfQfVoUHHa9Q0Opnp7EJQgo0pCEkN0bSCyarIBheav/u9e/Q7dQGbzp9arJKnjzZzYwDH7nOYwRwd4J3Vg7DbTDDCv8ouZbxadZMIo750z3PuDp4MSqq70NWaM1pJAaMDTyisIDW@Xs/ENUvZrKAVIFvfpQDPA4OqjQ023oEG7c/Mvu1K6IbQyZTyzLl2c@kDPc9dWLiwdGHer3f9nM3V/2LpziJRSQzu0N0CZ6KLrMawadsf)</kbd>.

Comment: Entiendo su punto, pero lo qué llevo ahora cómo clase de Programación, es Programación 1, Programación Orientada a Objetos (POO) la llevo dentro de 4 Semestres, no por ahora, entonces, se me es complejo entender su código, estimado.

Comment: Alguien editó mi pregunta y rechacé la edición, pero creo que me equivoqué y la edición estaba bien, mis disculpas.

Comment: ¿Ah?, No comprendo su ultimo comentario.